# Split delimited field into Different rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

So each day I'm given an Excel worksheet with orders, they look something like this:

```
Date        Vendor     OrderID/Quantity         Total 
12/28/2013  Nike       1111111-8;2222222-12     20
12/29/2013  Adidas     3333333-5;4444444-10     15
12/30/2013  Wrangler   5555555-3                3
```

It's usable to most people I work with but not to me, as I want to identify each OrderID separate from the quantity. The "-" between the 7 digit number is to separate the ID from how many units are associated to it. But essentially when I import this table into access I want to create another table that splits these values.

```
Date        Vendor     OrderID  Quantity        
12/28/2013  Nike       1111111  8               
12/28/2013  Nike       2222222  12              
12/29/2013  Adidas     3333333  5               
12/29/2013  Adidas     4444444  10              
12/30/2013  Wrangler   5555555  3
```

This is much more useful to me but has been a daunting task to produce with two delimiters("-" and ";"). I am ok with VBA but I am struggling to find a solution to my conflict. So how would I go about doing this?

Comment: When you say a "table of orders", is this coming in as an Excel spreadsheet?  SQL Server table?  Text file?  How are you getting this table?  Depending on the source, you may want to attack it differently so that info is crucial.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I apologize, left out that detail, currently it comes in as an Excel sheet

Comment: I was first going to suggest setting up an Excel template based on your response, but after looking at Blackhawk's answer I think it's probably easier and more reliable.  Rather than importing the spreadsheet you may be able to just link it and run the VBA against the linked sheet.  I'm not positive of the frequency of your data pulls and how they're named, but if it's an option then that will save you some extra work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward way I can think of is the VBA [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function.  Please note that I set up the `tblStaging` staging table with all the fields as Text type for the import from Excel, but I set the `tblOrders` table up with (what I assume are) the correct types: Date as Date, Vendor as Text, OrderID as Number and Quantity as Number.  See the comments in the code for details.

```
Public Sub SplitOrders()
    Dim rsStaging As Recordset
    Dim rsOrder As Recordset
    Dim arrOrders() As String
    Dim arrOrderDetails() As String

    'Rename these for whatever your tables are called'
    Set rsStaging = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblStaging")
    Set rsOrder = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblOrders")

    rsStaging.MoveFirst
    While Not rsStaging.EOF

        'Split into an array of Orders'
        arrOrders = Split(rsStaging.Fields("OrderID/Quantity"), ";")

        For i = 0 To UBound(arrOrders)

            'Split the OrderID and Quantity for each Order'
            arrOrderDetails = Split(arrOrders(i), "-")

            'Create the new record in tblOrders'
            With rsOrder
                .AddNew
                !Date = CDate(rsStaging!Date)
                !Vendor = rsStaging!Vendor
                !OrderID = CLng(arrOrderDetails(0)) 'If the OrderID can contain letters, symbols or leading zeros, omit the CLng( ... ) call'
                !Quantity = CLng(arrOrderDetails(1))
                .Update
            End With

        Next
        rsStaging.MoveNext
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice.  The array members are all string type, so he may need to cast them to match the datatype of the destination fields, eg `!OrderID = CLng(arrOrderDetails(0))`

Comment: +1 for thinking of using the UBound of the array to determine the loop size.  I was half-way through a more convoluted solution and decided this one was better.

Answer (score 2):

I'd look to break this down into different pieces rather than trying to parse the data all at once. For example, step 1 might be to import the file to a staging table (that looks like the first data example from your question). Step 2 would be to query the table to detect any rows that contain ';' (perhaps using the InStr function or a wildcard search `like '*;*'`. Take these records and parse them into two or more records. Third, identify any records that do not contain ';' and parse those into single records. All of the resulting (clean) records can go into your destination table for further analysis.